# Route an aspx url to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I simply wants to route a URL which is not in the MVC project.
Like

```
http://mysite.com/Parents/default.aspx?ID=xxx
```

TO

```
http://mysite.com/accounts/login
```

with the ID

Answer (score 6):

I think something like this would work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Parents/default.aspx?ID={id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Parents/default.aspx",
            defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

its says -  The resource cannot be found /parents/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect all .aspx pages to redirect at "accounts/login" then do like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Page",
   "{name}.aspx",
   new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```